# memoize to disk - Python - persistent memoization

Tags: python, memoization

Is there a way to memoize the output of a function to disk?

I have a function

```
def getHtmlOfUrl(url):
    ... # expensive computation
```

and would like to do something like:

```
def getHtmlMemoized(url) = memoizeToFile(getHtmlOfUrl, "file.dat")
```

and then call getHtmlMemoized(url), to do the expensive computation only once for each url.

Comment: Just pickle (or use json) the cache dict.

Comment: thanks but I am a python newbie (second day). I don't have the slightest idea what you mean...

Comment: Rather than trying to reinvent this wheel, here's a library that does that quite well, and is robust against all sorts of corner cases you won't anticipate until much later (concurrency, disk usage, thundering herd):  https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/dogpile.cache

Comment: You can use the library redis-simple-cache which does exactly this, persistent memoisation of function calls. Check it out : https://github.com/vivekn/redis-simple-cache

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, the better redis cache to use now is https://pypi.org/project/python-redis-cache/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Python offers a very elegant way to do this - decorators. Basically, a decorator is a function that wraps another function to provide additional functionality without changing the function source code. Your decorator can be written like this:

```
import json

def persist_to_file(file_name):

    def decorator(original_func):

        try:
            cache = json.load(open(file_name, 'r'))
        except (IOError, ValueError):
            cache = {}

        def new_func(param):
            if param not in cache:
                cache[param] = original_func(param)
                json.dump(cache, open(file_name, 'w'))
            return cache[param]

        return new_func

    return decorator
```

Once you've got that, 'decorate' the function using @-syntax and you're ready.

```
@persist_to_file('cache.dat')
def html_of_url(url):
    your function code...
```

Note that this decorator is intentionally simplified and may not work for every situation, for example, when the source function accepts or returns data that cannot be json-serialized.

More on decorators: [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python/1594484#1594484)

And here's how to make the decorator save the cache just once, at exit time:

```
import json, atexit

def persist_to_file(file_name):

    try:
        cache = json.load(open(file_name, 'r'))
    except (IOError, ValueError):
        cache = {}

    atexit.register(lambda: json.dump(cache, open(file_name, 'w')))

    def decorator(func):
        def new_func(param):
            if param not in cache:
                cache[param] = func(param)
            return cache[param]
        return new_func

    return decorator
```

Comment: This will write a new file every time the cache is updated - dependent on the use case this may (or may not) defeat the speedup you get from memoization....

Comment: it *also* contains a very nice race condition, if this decorator is used concurrently, or (more likely), in a re-entrant fashion.  if `a()` and `b()` are both memoized, and `a()` calls `b()`, the cache can be read for `a()`, and then again for `b()`,  first b's result is memoized, but then the stale cache from the call to a overwrites it, b's contribution to the cache is lost.

Comment: @root: sure, `atexit` would be perhaps a better place for flushing the cache. On the other side, adding premature optimizations might defeat the educational purpose of this code.

Comment: surely in the general case it'd be better to pickle rather than serialize to json. also the stdlib contains this https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html which wraps the pickling in a dict style interface... pretty much a readymade cache system, just add decorator

Comment: I made a package called  [simpler](https://pypi.org/project/simpler/) with an annotation `simpler.files.disk_cache` that fits exactly this purpose, including a cache lifetime and argument-aware caching using annotation parameters.

Comment: is there a way to use this decorator inside an instance method ?

Comment: This won't work if the function that you are memoizing has multiple arguments.  A quick fix is to change the `def new_func` line to `def new_func(*args, **kwargs):`;`param=str([args, kwargs])` and then you need to change the call to `func`, too.

Comment: I found this very useful.  I'll just add that if you want to have the ability to clear the cache or add some metadata to it (such as data attribution), you can bind the related dict methods for `cache` to `new_func` within the decorator, such as `new_func.clear_cache = cache.clear` and `new_func.update_cache = cache.update` immediately before the `return new_func` line. Then say your wrapped function is named `expensive_function(args)`, you can clear the cache with `expensive_function.clear_cache()`.  This is similar to how functools adds the clear_cache option.

Answer (score 62):

Check out [`joblib.Memory`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Memory.html). It's a library for doing exactly that.

```
from joblib import Memory
memory = Memory("cachedir")
@memory.cache
def f(x):
    print('Running f(%s)' % x)
    return x
```

Comment: pros: Works for me, and it's super fast.  cons: The folder names are letters and numbers like `3e2bbf56be556090e768d65967cb9122`, and the outputs are `.pkl` files so I can't easily see what the cached data looks like.

Comment: Be also prepared that it inspects the code of the cached function. Each time you change whatever in that function, the cache gets invalidated. You cannot turn this feature off unless you manually change the joblib source code.

Answer (score 29):

A cleaner solution powered by Python's [Shelve module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html). The advantage is the cache gets updated in real time via well-known `dict` syntax, also it's exception proof(no need to handle annoying `KeyError`).

```
import shelve
def shelve_it(file_name):
    d = shelve.open(file_name)

    def decorator(func):
        def new_func(param):
            if param not in d:
                d[param] = func(param)
            return d[param]

        return new_func

    return decorator

@shelve_it('cache.shelve')
def expensive_funcion(param):
    pass
```

This will facilitate the function to be computed just once. Next subsequent calls will return the stored result.

Comment: How do you make it multi-parameter?

Comment: @RogerS change the decorator so that it accepts *args **kwargs.

Comment: As implemented here, this solution doesn't appear to work in 3.9, unless param happens to be a string; If `param` is any other data type it will throw an AttributeError due to not having `encode`. 
You'll also get collisions if you have multiple functions using the decorator with similar parameters. I did get this to work with modifications. Add `writeback=True`. Set `key = f"{func.__name__}", if key not in d, set `d[key] == {}`, then `func_cache = d[key]`.  Then replace references to `d` inside `new_func` with `func_cache`.  I also declared `d` as global, and then `d.sync()` before exit

Comment: Correcting myself a bit here, there won't be any parameter collision for multiple functions as each function gets it's own cache file, but the problem with needing to convert param to str() still stands.

Answer (score 25):

There is also [`diskcache`](https://pypi.org/project/diskcache/).

```py
from diskcache import Cache

cache = Cache("cachedir")

@cache.memoize()
def f(x, y):
    print('Running f({}, {})'.format(x, y))
    return x, y
```

Comment: if the function to be memoized is a method of an object, and the `cache` variable is init-ed in that object, how can this be employed ?

Comment: It's simple to use and works well.  It stores all the cached data in a file called `cache.db` within the cache dir you specify.

Comment: @Ciprian Tomoiagă I guess there's no easy way. You'll have to manually do it.

Comment: The way for me was to still use a global cache object. Made no sense to have it inside the object, only complicated things a lot. It even worked with multiprocessing quite well once I made it global

Comment: Two things I like about this library: First, the keyword arguments are treated order independent. Changing the order of keyword arguments does not invalidate the cache. Cachier library does not have this capability. Secondly, it does not try to inspect the function code and invalidate the cache when function code changes. In contrast, joblib invalidates the cache when function code is changed, and you cannot turn this feature off.

Answer (score 6):

The [Artemis library](https://github.com/QUVA-Lab/artemis) has a module for this.  (you'll need to `pip install artemis-ml`)

You decorate your function:

```
from artemis.fileman.disk_memoize import memoize_to_disk

@memoize_to_disk
def fcn(a, b, c = None):
    results = ...
    return results
```

Internally, it makes a hash out of input arguments and saves memo-files by this hash.

Comment: How fast is it compared to `shelve`?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [Cachier](https://github.com/shaypal5/cachier). It supports additional cache configuration parameters like TTL etc.

Simple example:

```
from cachier import cachier
import datetime

@cachier(stale_after=datetime.timedelta(days=3))
def foo(arg1, arg2):
  """foo now has a persistent cache, trigerring recalculation for values stored more than 3 days."""
  return {'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2}
```

Comment: The keyword arguments are now treated in Cachier in order independent way, so changing the order of function arguments will not invalidate the cache. But it is unable to hash dict, list, etc objects provided as argument values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cache_to_disk package:

```
    from cache_to_disk import cache_to_disk

    @cache_to_disk(3)
    def my_func(a, b, c, d=None):
        results = ...
        return results
```

This will cache the results for 3 days, specific to the arguments a, b, c and d. The results are stored in a pickle file on your machine, and unpickled and returned next time the function is called. After 3 days, the pickle file is deleted until the function is re-run. The function will be re-run whenever the function is called with new arguments. More info here: https://github.com/sarenehan/cache_to_disk

Answer (score 1):

Most answers are in a decorator fashion. But maybe I don't want to cache the result every time when calling the function.

I made one solution using context manager, so the function can be called as

```
with DiskCacher('cache_id', myfunc) as myfunc2:
    res=myfunc2(...)
```

when you need the caching functionality.

The 'cache_id' string is used to distinguish data files, which are named `[calling_script]_[cache_id].dat`. So if you are doing this in a loop, will need to incorporate the looping variable into this `cache_id`, otherwise data will be overwritten.

Alternatively:

```
myfunc2=DiskCacher('cache_id')(myfunc)
res=myfunc2(...)
```

Alternatively (this is probably not quite useful as the same id is used all time time):

```
@DiskCacher('cache_id')
def myfunc(*args):
    ...
```

The complete code with examples (I'm using `pickle` to save/load, but can be changed to whatever save/read methods. NOTE that this is also assuming the function in question returns only 1 return value):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, os
import functools

def formFilename(folder, varid):
    '''Compose abspath for cache file

    Args:
        folder (str): cache folder path.
        varid (str): variable id to form file name and used as variable id.
    Returns:
        abpath (str): abspath for cache file, which is using the <folder>
            as folder. The file name is the format:
                [script_file]_[varid].dat
    '''
    script_file=os.path.splitext(sys.argv[0])[0]
    name='[%s]_[%s].nc' %(script_file, varid)
    abpath=os.path.join(folder, name)

    return abpath


def readCache(folder, varid, verbose=True):
    '''Read cached data

    Args:
        folder (str): cache folder path.
        varid (str): variable id.
    Keyword Args:
        verbose (bool): whether to print some text info.
    Returns:
        results (tuple): a tuple containing data read in from cached file(s).
    '''
    import pickle
    abpath_in=formFilename(folder, varid)
    if os.path.exists(abpath_in):
        if verbose:
            print('\n# <readCache>: Read in variable', varid,
                    'from disk cache:\n', abpath_in)
        with open(abpath_in, 'rb') as fin:
            results=pickle.load(fin)

    return results


def writeCache(results, folder, varid, verbose=True):
    '''Write data to disk cache

    Args:
        results (tuple): a tuple containing data read to cache.
        folder (str): cache folder path.
        varid (str): variable id.
    Keyword Args:
        verbose (bool): whether to print some text info.
    '''
    import pickle
    abpath_out=formFilename(folder, varid)
    if verbose:
        print('\n# <writeCache>: Saving output to:\n',abpath_out)
    with open(abpath_out, 'wb') as fout:
        pickle.dump(results, fout)

    return


class DiskCacher(object):
    def __init__(self, varid, func=None, folder=None, overwrite=False,
            verbose=True):
        '''Disk cache context manager

        Args:
            varid (str): string id used to save cache.
                function <func> is assumed to return only 1 return value.
        Keyword Args:
            func (callable): function object whose return values are to be
                cached.
            folder (str or None): cache folder path. If None, use a default.
            overwrite (bool): whether to force a new computation or not.
            verbose (bool): whether to print some text info.
        '''

        if folder is None:
            self.folder='/tmp/cache/'
        else:
            self.folder=folder

        self.func=func
        self.varid=varid
        self.overwrite=overwrite
        self.verbose=verbose

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.func is None:
            raise Exception("Need to provide a callable function to __init__() when used as context manager.")

        return _Cache2Disk(self.func, self.varid, self.folder,
                self.overwrite, self.verbose)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        return

    def __call__(self, func=None):
        _func=func or self.func
        return _Cache2Disk(_func, self.varid, self.folder, self.overwrite,
                self.verbose)



def _Cache2Disk(func, varid, folder, overwrite, verbose):
    '''Inner decorator function

    Args:
        func (callable): function object whose return values are to be
            cached.
        varid (str): variable id.
        folder (str): cache folder path.
        overwrite (bool): whether to force a new computation or not.
        verbose (bool): whether to print some text info.
    Returns:
        decorated function: if cache exists, the function is <readCache>
            which will read cached data from disk. If needs to recompute,
            the function is wrapped that the return values are saved to disk
            before returning.
    '''

    def decorator_func(func):
        abpath_in=formFilename(folder, varid)

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if os.path.exists(abpath_in) and not overwrite:
                results=readCache(folder, varid, verbose)
            else:
                results=func(*args, **kwargs)
                if not os.path.exists(folder):
                    os.makedirs(folder)
                writeCache(results, folder, varid, verbose)
            return results
        return wrapper

    return decorator_func(func)



if __name__=='__main__':

    data=range(10)  # dummy data

    #--------------Use as context manager--------------
    def func1(data, n):
        '''dummy function'''
        results=[i*n for i in data]
        return results

    print('\n### Context manager, 1st time call')
    with DiskCacher('context_mananger', func1) as func1b:
        res=func1b(data, 10)
        print('res =', res)

    print('\n### Context manager, 2nd time call')
    with DiskCacher('context_mananger', func1) as func1b:
        res=func1b(data, 10)
        print('res =', res)

    print('\n### Context manager, 3rd time call with overwrite=True')
    with DiskCacher('context_mananger', func1, overwrite=True) as func1b:
        res=func1b(data, 10)
        print('res =', res)

    #--------------Return a new function--------------
    def func2(data, n):
        results=[i*n for i in data]
        return results

    print('\n### Wrap a new function, 1st time call')
    func2b=DiskCacher('new_func')(func2)
    res=func2b(data, 10)
    print('res =', res)

    print('\n### Wrap a new function, 2nd time call')
    res=func2b(data, 10)
    print('res =', res)

    #----Decorate a function using the syntax sugar----
    @DiskCacher('pie_dec')
    def func3(data, n):
        results=[i*n for i in data]
        return results

    print('\n### pie decorator, 1st time call')
    res=func3(data, 10)
    print('res =', res)

    print('\n### pie decorator, 2nd time call.')
    res=func3(data, 10)
    print('res =', res)
```

The outputs:

```
### Context manager, 1st time call

# <writeCache>: Saving output to:
 /tmp/cache/[diskcache]_[context_mananger].nc
res = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

### Context manager, 2nd time call

# <readCache>: Read in variable context_mananger from disk cache:
 /tmp/cache/[diskcache]_[context_mananger].nc
res = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

### Context manager, 3rd time call with overwrite=True

# <writeCache>: Saving output to:
 /tmp/cache/[diskcache]_[context_mananger].nc
res = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

### Wrap a new function, 1st time call

# <writeCache>: Saving output to:
 /tmp/cache/[diskcache]_[new_func].nc
res = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

### Wrap a new function, 2nd time call

# <readCache>: Read in variable new_func from disk cache:
 /tmp/cache/[diskcache]_[new_func].nc
res = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

### pie decorator, 1st time call

# <writeCache>: Saving output to:
 /tmp/cache/[diskcache]_[pie_dec].nc
res = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

### pie decorator, 2nd time call.

# <readCache>: Read in variable pie_dec from disk cache:
 /tmp/cache/[diskcache]_[pie_dec].nc
res = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
import json

class Memoize(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.memo = {}

    def load_memo(filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            self.memo.update(json.load(f))

    def save_memo(filename):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.memo, f)

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not args in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.func(*args)
        return self.memo[args]
```

Basic usage:

```
your_mem_func = Memoize(your_func)
your_mem_func.load_memo('yourdata.json')
#  do your stuff with your_mem_func
```

If you want to write your *"cache"* to a file after using it -- to be loaded again in the future:

```
your_mem_func.save_memo('yournewdata.json')
```

Comment: @seguso - updated on the usage. More on memoization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python

Comment: @Merlin - This is a classic case of memoization where a class should (or could as well) be used...

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I mean by memoize. I don't want to manually manage loading and saving to disk. This should be transparent.

Comment: @seguso - then go with *thg435* variant, but note that it will write to a file every time the cache is updated - that may end up defeating the purpose of memoization. (in this case you can manage the writes, while you still need to load the file only once)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you data is json serializable, this code should work

```
import os, json

def json_file(fname):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if os.path.isfile(fname):
                with open(fname, 'r') as f:
                    ret = json.load(f)
            else:
                with open(fname, 'w') as f:
                    ret = function(*args, **kwargs)
                    json.dump(ret, f)
            return ret
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

decorate `getHtmlOfUrl` and then simply call it, if it had been run previously, you will get your cached data.

Checked with python 2.x and python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with which can:

- memoize mutable objects (memoized functions should have no side effects that change mutable parameters or it won't work as expected)
- writes to a separate cache file for each wrapped function (easy to delete the file to purge that particular cache)
- compresses the data to make it much smaller on disk (a LOT smaller)

It will create cache files like:

```
cache.__main__.function.getApiCall.db
cache.myModule.function.fixDateFormat.db
cache.myOtherModule.function.getOtherApiCall.db
```

Here's the code.  You can choose a compression library of your choosing, but I've found LZMA works best for the pickle storage we are using.

```
import dbm
import hashlib
import pickle
# import bz2
import lzma

# COMPRESSION = bz2
COMPRESSION = lzma # better with pickle compression

# Create a @memoize_to_disk decorator to cache a memoize to disk cache
def memoize_to_disk(function, cache_filename=None):
    uniqueFunctionSignature = f'cache.{function.__module__}.{function.__class__.__name__}.{function.__name__}'
    if cache_filename is None:
        cache_filename = uniqueFunctionSignature
        # print(f'Caching to {cache_file}')
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Convert the dictionary into a JSON object (can't memoize mutable fields, this gives us an immutable, hashable function signature)
        if cache_filename == uniqueFunctionSignature:
            # Cache file is function-specific, so don't include function name in params
            params = {'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs} 
        else:
            # add module.class.function name to params so no collisions occur if user overrides cache_file with the same cache for multiple functions
            params = {'function': uniqueFunctionSignature, 'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs}

        # key hash of the json representation of the function signature (to avoid immutable dictionary errors)
        params_json = json.dumps(params)  
        key = hashlib.sha256(params_json.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()  # store hash of key
        # Get cache entry or create it if not found
        with dbm.open(cache_filename, 'c') as db:
            # Try to retrieve the result from the cache
            try:
                result = pickle.loads(COMPRESSION.decompress(db[key]))
                # print(f'CACHE HIT: Found {key[1:100]=} in {cache_file=} with value {str(result)[0:100]=}')
                return result
            except KeyError:
                # If the result is not in the cache, call the function and store the result
                result = function(*args, **kwargs)
                db[key] = COMPRESSION.compress(pickle.dumps(result))
                # print(f'CACHE MISS: Stored {key[1:100]=} in {cache_file=} with value {str(result)[0:100]=}')
                return result
    return wrapper
```

To use the code, use the @memoize_to_disk decorator (with an optional filename parameter if you don't like "cache." as a prefix)

```
@memoize_to_disk
def expensive_example(n):
  // expensive operation goes here
  return value
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general version of the top answer that also works for multiple arguments and non-hashable arguments, can save to file either each time or only when the program is terminated, can save either the string reprentation of the arguments or their hash, pretty prints in a readable JSON file and has a `verbose` flag for debugging:

```
import json
import atexit
import hashlib
from functools import wraps

def persist_to_file(file_name, readable=True, save_file_each_time=False, verbose=0, use_hash=False):
    """
    A decorator that memoizes the results of a function and persists them to a file.

    Parameters:
        - file_name (str): The name of the file to store the memoized results.
        - readable (bool): If True, the JSON file will be indented for readability.
        - save_file_each_time (bool): If True, the file will be saved after each function call.
                                If False, the file will be saved only at the end (default).
        - verbose (int): Level of verbosity. 0 for no verbosity, 1 for high-level info,
                         2 for detailed info about arguments and results.
        - use_hash (bool): If true uses the hash of the `repr` rather than the `repr` as
                                the key, saves disk space for large arguments but increases computation and
                                reduces human readibility of the cache file.  

    Usage:
        @persist_to_file("memoized_results.json", readable=True, save_file_each_time=True, verbose=2)
        def addition(a, b):
            return a + b
        
        # Just call the function normally, afterwards, results will be memoized,
        # both in the same run and in successive runs
        addition(2, 3)
        addition(2, 3)

    Note:
        The `save_file_each_time` parameter is particularly useful for APIs with Uvicorn,
        ensuring that the memoized results are saved correctly.
    """

    try:
        cache = json.load(open(file_name, 'r'))
    except (IOError, ValueError):
        cache = {}

    def save_to_file():
        json.dump(cache, open(file_name, 'w'), indent=4 if readable else 0)

    if not save_file_each_time:
        atexit.register(save_to_file)

    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
            # Convert arguments to a hashable format
            if use_hash:
                args_key = hashlib.md5(repr((args, kwargs)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            else:
                args_key = repr((args, kwargs))

            if args_key not in cache:
                if verbose == 1:
                    print(f"Computing: {func.__name__}")
                elif verbose == 2:
                    print(f"Computing: {func.__name__} with args: {args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")

                cache[args_key] = func(*args, **kwargs)

                if save_file_each_time:
                    save_to_file()

                if verbose:
                    print(f"Result saved")
            else:
                if verbose == 1:
                    print(f"Result retrieved from cache: {func.__name__}")
                elif verbose == 2:
                    print(f"Result retrieved from cache: {func.__name__} with args: {args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")
            if verbose == 2:
                print(f"Result: {cache[args_key]}")

            return cache[args_key]

        return new_func

    return decorator

if __name__ == "__main__":
    @persist_to_file("temp_memo_test.json", readable=True, save_file_each_time=False, verbose=2, use_hash=False)
    def verbose_add(a, b):
        print("Doing addition!!", a, b)
        return a + b

    results = [
        verbose_add(1, 2),
        verbose_add(1, 2),
        verbose_add(5, 3),
        verbose_add([1], [2]),
    ]
    print(results)
```

First run has the output:

```
Computing: verbose_add with args: (1, 2), kwargs: {}
Doing addition!! 1 2
Result saved
Result: 3
Result retrieved from cache: verbose_add with args: (1, 2), kwargs: {}
Result: 3
Computing: verbose_add with args: (5, 3), kwargs: {}
Doing addition!! 5 3
Result saved
Result: 8
Computing: verbose_add with args: ([1], [2]), kwargs: {}
Doing addition!! [1] [2]
Result saved
Result: [1, 2]
[3, 3, 8, [1, 2]]
```

Second run:

```
Result retrieved from cache: verbose_add with args: (1, 2), kwargs: {}
Result: 3
Result retrieved from cache: verbose_add with args: (1, 2), kwargs: {}
Result: 3
Result retrieved from cache: verbose_add with args: (5, 3), kwargs: {}
Result: 8
Result retrieved from cache: verbose_add with args: ([1], [2]), kwargs: {}
Result: [1, 2]
[3, 3, 8, [1, 2]]
```

The disk cache file `temp_memo_test.json`:

```
{
    "((1, 2), {})": 3,
    "((5, 3), {})": 8,
    "(([1], [2]), {})": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import shelve
import weakref

def shelve_cache(cache_file):
    def decorator(func):
        def changed_func(key,*arg,usecache=True,**args):
            if changed_func.debug:
                print(f'cache_file:{changed_func.cache_file} {changed_func.func.__name__}{(key,arg,usecache,args)}')
            if (not usecache) or (key not in changed_func.d):
                res = changed_func.func(key,*arg,**args)
                changed_func.d[key] = res
                return res
            else:
                try:
                    if changed_func.debug:
                        print(f'\treturn {changed_func.d[key]}')
                    return changed_func.d[key]
                except Exception as e:
                    try: changed_func.d[key]=None #might fix a truncated save file
                    except: pass
                    try: del changed_func.d[key] #might fix a truncated save file
                    except: pass
                    print('Exception shelve_cache',key,e.__class__.__name__,e)
                    res = changed_func.func(key,*arg,**args)
                    changed_func.d[key] = res
                    return res
        def set_file(file):
            '''set/change cache file'''
            print(f'set_file {file}')
            changed_func.cache_file=file
            if getattr(changed_func, 'd', None):
                changed_func.finalize()
            changed_func.d = shelve.open(file)
            def atexit(d):
                '''auto save cache file at exit/CtrlC'''
                print(f'save {d}')
                d.close()
            changed_func.finalize = weakref.finalize(changed_func.d, atexit, changed_func.d)
        def sync():
            if getattr(changed_func, 'd', None):
                changed_func.d.sync()
        changed_func.debug=False
        changed_func.func=func
        changed_func.set_file = set_file
        changed_func.sync = sync
        set_file(cache_file)
        return changed_func
    return decorator

@shelve_cache('./tmp.download_status.cache')
def download_status(key,value='Unknown'):
    return value
# download_status=shelve_cache('./tmp.download_status.cache')(download_status) # only if don't use @shelve_cache()
download_status.debug=True
download_status('1')
download_status('1',usecache=False,value='download_status_ok')
download_status.sync()
download_status.set_file('./tmp.download_status2.cache')

download_status=download_status.func
```