# Using __delitem__ with a class object rather than an instance in Python

Tags: python, class, instance, class-method

I'd like to be able to use `__delitem__` with a class-level variable.
My use case can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085823/memoize-a-function-so-that-it-isnt-reset-when-i-rerun-the-file-in-python) (the answer that uses `_reg_funcs`) but it basically involves a decorator class keeping a list of all the functions it has decorated. Is there a way I can get the class object to support `__delitem__`? I know I could keep an instance around specially for this purpose but I'd rather not have to do that.

```
class Foo(object):
    _instances = {}

    def __init__(self, my_str):
        n = len(self._instances) + 1
        self._instances[my_str] = n
        print "Now up to {} instances".format(n)

    @classmethod
    def __delitem__(cls, my_str):
        del cls._instances[my_str]


abcd = Foo('abcd')
defg = Foo('defg')

print "Deleting via instance..."
del abcd['abcd']
print "Done!\n"

print "Deleting via class object..."
del Foo['defg']
print "You'll never get here because of a TypeError: 'type' object does not support item deletion"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write `del obj[key]`, Python calls the `__delitem__` method of the class of `obj`, not of `obj`. So `del obj[key]` results in `type(obj).__delitem__(obj, key)`.

In your case, that means `type(Foo).__delitem__(Foo, 'abcd')`. `type(Foo)` is `type`, and `type.__delitem__` is not defined. You can't modify `type` itself, you'll need to change the type of `Foo` itself to something that does.

You do that by defining a new *metaclass*, which is simply a subclass of `type`, then instructing Python to use your new metaclass to create the `Foo` class (not instances of `Foo`, but `Foo` itself).

```
class ClassMapping(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        t = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        t._instances = {}
        return t
    def __delitem__(cls, my_str):
        del cls._instances[my_str]

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = ClassMapping
    def __init__(self, my_str):
        n = len(Foo._instances) + 1
        Foo._instances[my_str] = n
        print "Now up to {} instances".format(n)
```

Changing the metaclass of `Foo` from `type` to `ClassMapping` provides `Foo` with

1. a class variable `_instances` that refers to a dictionary
2. a `__delitem__` method that removes arguments from `_instances`.

Comment: Works, thanks. But I'm surprised that "when you write del obj[key], Python calls the __delitem__ method of the class of obj, not of obj." Why is this?

Comment: Like any method, the function is tied to the class, not the object, and the object is the implicit first argument to the function. Trying to make `__delitem__` a class method instead of a regular instance method would be a special case which Python simply does not implement.